# Is there a programattic API to access vault info on a SanDisk SecureAccess drive?

Tags: usb-drive

The simple question version is as stated: Is there a programmatic API to access vault info on a SanDisk SecureAccess drive (without installing the SecureAccess manager UI)?

Here's what the business requirements are though, in case anyone can suggest an alternate solution.

1. Secure information on USB drive so that it cannot be copied to another drive.
2. Access this information via C# .NET 2.0.
3. Cannot call a remote service to check for keys/validate/etc. It must be self-contained.

We were previously using SanDisk USB drives with U3 but this technology has been discontinued. We basically need a "1 application instance per UBS drive" solution.